# creating new column in an R dataframe based on values in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, replace

I have the following data frame including restaurants (id#), owner and purchase date. Sometimes the restaurant changes ownership, but for analysis purposes I want to create another column which only keeps the name of the latest owner, this is determined by the "purchase date". How can I create this new column? In this example restaurant 23 changes hand on 1/1/2013, so I want to include only the new owner's name (Bob) as the current owner for all rows for this restaurant as shown below. If the restaurant does not change hands, keep the same name for the "current owner" column as the "owner" column.

```
    Restaurant <- c(23,23,23,23,23,23,23,15,15,15,15,17,17,17,17)

    owner <- c("Chuck","Chuck","Chuck","Chuck","Bob","Bob","Bob",
    "Hazel","Hazel","Hazel","Hazel","Pete","Pete","Pete","Pete")

    purchaseDate <- c("3/4/2011","3/4/2011","3/4/2011","3/4/2011",
    "1/1/2013","1/1/2013","1/1/2013","4/11/2010","4/11/2010","4/11/2010",
    "4/11/2010","9/2/2012","9/2/2012","9/2/2012","9/2/2012")

    df <- data.frame( Restaurant = Restaurant, owner=owner, purchaseDate=purchaseDate)

    df$currentOwner <- c("Bob","Bob","Bob","Bob","Bob","Bob","Bob","Hazel","Hazel","Hazel","Hazel","Pete","Pete","Pete","Pete")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$Restaurant, function(d)
        within(d, currentOwner2 <- as.character(
            owner[which.max(as.Date(purchaseDate, format="%d/%m/%Y"))]))))
```

Thanks @Thomas for excavating this question :-)